# How to I compute standard deviation of specific years using dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
Date        Price
2017-01-30  121
2017-03-31  559
2017-06-04  400
2017-09-05  327.26
2017-11-06  32.47
...
2021-03-24  7.62
2021-03-25  107.49
2021-04-26  319.42
2021-05-27  380.77
2021-07-30  32.11
```

I can't seem to calculate standard deviation for specific years (e.g. sd for year 2017 only). I have tried to use iloc to specific years while using the .std function but I received type error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or do you mean by?

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
print(df.loc[df['Date'].dt.year.eq(2017), 'Price'].std())
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert to datetimes and extract years by [`Series.dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

For all years use [`GroupBy.std`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.std.html):

```
s = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.year)['Price'].std()
#then is possible extract one year
out = s[2017]
```

If need only one year use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
out = df.loc[df['Date'].dt.year == 2017, 'Price'].std()
```